# How do I use NGINX as a frontend for a Legacy (Apache) Webserver

Tags: nginx, ssl, configuration, https

I have an NGINX server setup that is already hosting two applications, and SSL is set up on that NGINX server.

Now, I need to setup the NGINX server to be a front-end for a legacy Apache application so that the service that the legacy application is providing can be reached via SSL/HTTPS.

How do I configure my NGINX server to be a "pass through" server to the legacy application?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would put the SSL configuration in the frontend web server, and then simply forward without SSL to the backend server. If you have multiple backend servers, you will likely need vhosts.

The [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) mentions [this page which even goes through a full explanation of possibly exactly what you are doing](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-ssl-vhosts-under-nginx-plus-sni-support-ubuntu-11.04-debian-squeeze).